# duality between quiver variety and affine Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory

Let $\frak{g}$ be a ADE type simple lie algebra. There are (at least) two geometric ways to get highest weight irreducible representations of $\frak{g}$. One is by considering constructible functions on Nakajima varieties $\oplus_{v}(M(\mathcal{L}(v,w))\cap L(w))\cong V^\lambda$ and another one is by geometric Satake correspondence [Mirkovic-Vilonen] $IH^*(\overline{\text{Gr}^\lambda})\cong V^\lambda$. I heard that there is 'symplectic duality' connecting them. What is it exactly?

Comment: This answers the "reference request" tag, at least: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/search?a=braden+proudfoot+webster . Ben Webster will probably point you to which of his talks http://people.virginia.edu/~btw4e/talks.html goes into most detail about the quiver/Yangian case.